# How do i put the request result inside an html in express?

Tags: node.js, express

im trying to make a website using express, and in this website i request some data from an external API.
So, i have an html where i "send" the request. How do i take that parameters for the request into the server, and then the response to the html or at least the js linked to that html?
To this point, i already tested how to add an html with a js linked to it, and it worked, so now i have to make the rest of the web concept, that is request data from the API.

Sorry if i dont have the code, but im still making it and i have this big issue that i cant resolve.

Thanks for your time and advice anyways

Comment: Do you have a public html folder

Comment: yeah, i have it. and thanks anyway, im gonna go for another point of view to solve my problem. I will build a nodejs API that will connect to the external API, so i can query it from ajax in jquery

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices.

Either you make an ajax request to the api from the front-end or in the back-end and render the result.

You can also make a request from the front-end, send the result to the back-end and have express send a different response.

No code attached as your question is very generic.